# The lost Root domain

Tags: domain, domain-controller, root, controller

I recently took over the network of a mid size company. The problem I'm running into now is that the company's servers/users/everything is setup in the child domain, and there is no root DC to be found.

The domain function level is 2k3.

I need to know the best way to either recreate the root domain as I need to move the company back into the root domain.

Answer (score 2):

Man, that's pretty brutal. You might be best off making a new root domain and migrating everything with [ADMT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=20c0db45-db16-4d10-99f2-539b7277ccdb). Who knows what other black magic has been going on.

Comment: That was one of the option that I was considering, just not one that I was particularly looking forward to.

Comment: @Scott - It sucks and someone might know of a different way, but if I was walking into that infrastructure I wouldn't trust a damn thing.

Comment: Mark, believe me, the gas tank and match approach has crossed my mind many times.
At this point I think that I am indeed going with the idea to start a "fresh" root domain, and migrate everything over. Going to try to get everyone copied over and then pick a weekend and move all the servers into the domain and just have a hell of a monday getting everyone's accounts and PC's switched over to the new domain.